# Not getting Select Options in Angular

Tags: angular, select

Template code is

```
<select class="input-field form-control" id="story_category_id" name="story_category_id 
materialize="material_select" required>
<option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
<option *ngFor="let category of categories">{{ category.name }}</option>
</select>
```

TS code is

```
categories = [
{id: 1, name: 'Art and Culture'},
{id: 2, name: 'Science and Technology'},
{id: 3, name: 'Health'},
{id: 4, name: 'Education and Skilling'},
{id: 5, name: 'Environment Sustainability ( including Agriculture, water, Climate)'},
{id: 6, name: 'Governance and Administration'},
{id: 7, name: 'Business and Entrepreneurship'},
{id: 8, name: 'Poverty and Hunger'},
{id: 9, name: 'Religion, Social Justice and Strong Institutions'},
{id: 10, name: 'Rural Development'}
]
```

option list is not displaying even it its not giving any error

Comment: Your code seems fine. Can you create stackblitz of your code?

Comment: You code seems to work just fine: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ktypxk
but missed a quote somewhere : 
`name="story_category_id"`